# Type E recognized as an Object

Tags: java, methods, generic-programming

why if I write this:

```
Node<Vertex<E>, Double> a = queue.extractMax();
Vertex<E> u = a.getValue();
```

The code compile without errors and if I write this:

```
Vertex<E> u = queue.extractMax().getValue();
```

I got the error:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Vertex

Comment: Which Java version, compiler and compiler version?

Comment: What's the signature of `extractMax()`?

Comment: Likely you have a different signature. It would work if you do `Vertex<E> u = ((Node<Vertex<E>, Double>) queue.extractMax()).getValue();`

Comment: Java 9. public Node extractMax()

Comment: If he has a different signature than Node<Vertex<E>, Double> a = queue.extractMax(); won't work either without a cast

Comment: That's the problem when you return raw type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `extractMax()` signature/return type is different from `Node<Vertex<E>, Double>` -

```
Vertex<E> u = ((Node<Vertex<E>, Double>) queue.extractMax()).getValue();
```

This one should definitely work according your example.